# Convert weights to kilogram based on units column

Tags: r

I have a very large dataset which includes two columns for weights and weights units. Now I want to convert all the weights to Kilograms based on what appears on units columns. here is how the dataframe looks like

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "weights" = c(2.1,1500, 2500), "Units" = c("Kilograms","Grams", "Grams"))
```

So I want to write a code which looks at the units column and once it sees Grams, it automatically converts the weights in weight column to kilogram

here is expected outcome

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "weights" = c(2.1,1.5, 2.5), "Units" = c("Kilograms","Kilograms", "Kilograms"))
x
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and replace the gram values by slicing by `x$Units == "Grams"` for values in `x$weights`, then just replace "Grams" with "Kilograms". Something like this:

```r
x$weights[x$Units == "Grams"] <- x$weights[x$Units == "Grams"] / 1000
x$Units <- "Kilograms"
```

Alternatively, you can use dplyr's `mutate` with `ifelse`:

```r
library(dplyr)

x %>% 
    mutate(weights = ifelse(Units == "Grams", weights / 1000, weights),
           Units = "Kilograms"
           )
```

#### Output:

```
  SN weights     Units
1  1     2.1 Kilograms
2  2     1.5 Kilograms
3  3     2.5 Kilograms
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[Units == "Grams",c("weights", "Units"):=list(weights/1000, "Kilograms")]

x
#   SN weights     Units
#1:  1     2.1 Kilograms
#2:  2     1.5 Kilograms
#3:  3     2.5 Kilograms
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
kilo_df <- within(df, {weights <- ifelse(Units != "Kilograms", weights / 1000, weights)
                       Units <- as.character("Kilograms")})
```